# Finding a max of a number provides me with Optional()

Tags: ios, swift

When trying to find the highest number in my array and display it on a label, I get my solution with an `Optional()` around it. What am I doing to cause this, also, how can I display my solution without the `Optional()` surrounding it in my label.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var game1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var game2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var game3: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var series: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var average: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var high: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {

   guard
            let text1 = game1.text,
            let text2 = game2.text,
            let text3 = game3.text
    else { return }

    guard
            let game1Results = Int(text1),
            let game2Results = Int(text2),
            let game3Results = Int(text3)
    else { return }

    let gameResultsArray = [game1Results, game2Results, game3Results]

    high.text = "\(String(describing: gameResultsArray.max()))"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`gameResultsArray.max()` returns Optional value

[**`max()`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688806-max) `@warn_unqualified_access func max() -> Element?`

> Returns the maximum element in the sequence.

Change your code like this

```
let gameResultsArray = [game1Results, game2Results, game3Results]
    if let maximumVal = gameResultsArray.max() {
    high.text = String(maximumVal)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer will work for you. You need to unwrap the optional returned to you by the `max()` function.

---

There are 5 ways to unwrap an optional.

1. if-let statement
2. guard statements
3. force unwrapping
4. nil-coalescing operator
5. optional chaining

watch the video which I have linked below if you are still confused. Hope that clears some stuff up.

source: https://youtu.be/HntTRJHtLtA

Answer (score 0):

The reason you’re seeing “Optional()” around the string representation is because it is, unsurprisingly, an “optional”. I’d suggest you refer to [The Swift Programming Language: Optionals](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID330).

You’re using `guard let` pattern to unwrap the other optionals, you might do the same with the result of `max`:

```
@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
    guard
        let text1 = game1.text,
        let text2 = game2.text,
        let text3 = game3.text,
        let value1 = Int(text1),
        let value2 = Int(text2),
        let value3 = Int(text3),
        let highScore = [value1, value2, value3].max()
    else { return }

    high.text = "\(highScore)"
}
```

---

I’d personally suggest not using `Int()` to convert user entered text string to a number because it is not “localized”. For example, U.S. users generally use `,` as a thousands separator (e.g. “10,000”), not all locales do so. For example, in Germany they use `.` (e.g. “10.000”). You can use a number formatter to convert user entered text into a number and back, honoring the device’s preferred locale preferences e.g.:

```
let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    return formatter
}()

@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
    guard
        let text1 = game1.text,
        let text2 = game2.text,
        let text3 = game3.text,
        let value1 = formatter.number(from: text1)?.intValue,
        let value2 = formatter.number(from: text2)?.intValue,
        let value3 = formatter.number(from: text3)?.intValue,
        let highScore = [value1, value2, value3].max()
    else { return }

    high.text = formatter.string(for: highScore)
}
```